# If Query Already Exists Then Delete the Entire Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that creates two queries, exports them to Excel and then deletes them. However, when I hit an error on my exporting, it doesn't make it the deletions. How would I go about checking to see if they already exist? And if they do, delete them so I can re-create them with the new/updated data?

Code so far:

```
Dim qdfNewQry As Object
Dim qdfNewWS As Object

'//----- qdfNewQry
If Not IsNull(DLookup("myExportQry", "MSysObjects", "Name='myExportQry'")) Then
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdfNewQry.Name
    Set qdfNewQry = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("myExportQry", exportQry)
Else
    Set qdfNewQry = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("myExportQry", exportQry)
End If

'//----- qdfNewWS
If Not IsNull(DLookup("myExportWS", "MSysObjects", "Name='myExportWS'")) Then
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdfNewWS.Name
    Set qdfNewWS = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("myExportWS", exportWS)
Else
    Set qdfNewWS = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("myExportWS", exportWS)
End If
```

I'm getting the error "The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'myExportQry'" on the line `If Not IsNull(DLookup("myExportQry", "MSysObjects", "Name='myExportQry'")) Then`

I'm pretty lost it seems. Any help/advice/corrections would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT1:**

Just for clarification, I'm wanting to delete the **entire** query. Other alternative solutions would also be welcome!

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in so you could step through the code and see exactly which line is causing the error?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Yes! My bad, forgot to put that into the post. Added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLookup uses the following format:

```
DLookup([Field], [Table], [Criteria])
```

There's no field in MSysObjects named "MyExportQuery".  So, the first argument in DLookup() is wrong.

Also, remember that when you use a reserved word (like "Name"), you need to enclose it in brackets.

I *think* you want to say,

```
DLookup("[ID]", "MSysObjects", "[Name]='myExportQry'")
```

That should either return a number or a NULL, so that will give you what you need to determine if the query already exists.

The above is untested, but logically it makes sense to me.

Comment: This looks as though it's only deleting a specific field from the queries rather than the queries themselves.

Comment: @Symon - That's odd, because MSysObjects only contains the query name.  In order to delete a specific field in the query, it would have to do that in MSysQueries.  I'm pretty sure your QueryDefs.Delete code is accurate.

Comment: Try using DeleteObject instead.  DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "myExportQry"

Comment: Had a mistype, This worked! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use the Dlookup function for this!

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb()
For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs
  Debug.Print qdf.Name
       If qdf.Name = "strQry" Then
          CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "strQry"
          CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh
          Exit For
       End If
Next qdf
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this. If the query is not there the DeleteObject will be "skipped"

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "myExportQry"
Set qdfTemp = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("myExportQry", "SELECT From ....")
```